# How to prove this integral inequality in a 2-D region?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, elliptic-pde, fields

Let $\Omega$ be a 2D region. Now we have a partial differential equation system describing the characteristics of the region:

\begin{align*} \nabla \cdot (h_0^3 P_0 \nabla P_0) &= 0 \\  \nabla \cdot [h_0^3 \nabla (P_0 P_1)] &= 3 h_1 \nabla \cdot (h_0^2 P_0 \nabla P_0) \end{align*}
where $ P_0 $ is determined by a boundary condition, $ P_0>0 $, also, $P_1=0$ on the boundary $\partial \Omega$. $h_0$ is an arbitrary distribution function, $ h_0>0 $, while $h_1$ is a constant value and $h_1 \ll h_0$.

How to prove the following integral inequality:
$$ \frac{\iint P_1 \mathrm{d} \Omega }{h_1} < \iint \frac{ P_0 }{h_0} \mathrm{d} \Omega $$

Comment: $h_0$ is just an arbitrary function, nothing to do with Probability theory.

Comment: Can we prove this by constructing intermediate variables like this:
\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot (h_0^3 \nabla P_{0c}) &= 0 \\
\nabla \cdot [h_0^3 \nabla ( P_{1c})] &= 3 h_1 \nabla \cdot (h_0^2 \nabla P_{0c} )
\end{align}   and we try to prove the following integral inequality:
$$ \frac{\iint P_1 \mathrm{d} \Omega }{h_1} 
< \frac{\iint P_{1c} \mathrm{d} \Omega }{h_1} 
< \iint \frac{ P_{0c} }{h_0} \mathrm{d} \Omega 
< \iint \frac{ P_0 }{h_0} \mathrm{d} \Omega $$

Comment: The middle P1c is less than P0c can be explained by physical meaning.